# Mongodb, mongoose, Schema structure. get a collection into a field of other collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema

I have a schema "Questions" it has like a dozen of questions in it, I can add and delete those questions, I need this collection reflected in a field of other collection - "User" with one additional field (nested in options).

Question Schema:

```
var QuestionScema = new mongoose.Schema({
  key: { type: String, required: true },
  label: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  page: { type: String, required: true },
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  options: [{ 
    key: {type: String, required: true}, 
    value: {type: String, required: true}
  }],
});
```

User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: { type: String, required: true },
    Email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    Password: { type: String, required: true },

    //this is where I need to reflect a Questions collection on each user, 
    //so that it will look something like this//

    Questions: [{
        key: {type: String, required: true},
        //here can be all other fields from Questions collection, that is not a problem
        options: [{ 
            key: {type: String, reuired: true},
            value: {type: String, reuired: true},
            counter: {type: Number, default: 0} //this is the additional field
        }]
    }],

    //

    Notifications: [{
        Title: { type: String },
        Data: { type: String },
        Created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }]
});
```

I can't figure out how to do that.
I have another collection of users, say User2 that will answer those questions from Questions collections and I need to keep track on Users schema (not User2, there I just save questions and answers) of how many times an option for that question is chosen.

A Questiuons entry can look like this:

```
  {
    key: Haveyouseenthismovie,
    label: Have you seen this movie?,
    name: Have you seen this movie?,
    page: 1,
    type: dropdown,
    options: [{ 
      key: yes, 
      value: yes
    }, { 
      key: no, 
      value: no
    }]
}
```

I want it to work like that (reflect a collection in field of each User) so I don't have to check if that question is in User collection if not add and if it is, is there an option that I need if it is than increment, if not than add that option (that user selected from options in that question in Questions schema) and increment. That looks like a bummer. So I figured that it will be better if that field will reflect a collection and I will just increment the option that I need on a question that I need.
Please help me figure that out, I don't have enough practise in mongo so I struggle with it sometimes :)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. As I understand, you need to maintain a list of collections, a list of users and another list where you will maintain for each user, how many questions were answered by them? Is this right? What is the purpose of counter here? Can you explain your exact problem statement?

Comment: I have three collections: Questions, Users, Users2. Questions is the collection where I store questions (and answer options for the question) for User2 to answer, on User2 I store a list of entries like {Q: 'have you senn a movie', A: 'yes' } but User2 is out of the problem, I need to keep track on User (not User2) of how many times each option of a question is answered by User2. so it will be like {name: Have you seen this movie?: {yes: 1, no: 0} or name: Have you seen this movie?: [{yes: 1}, {no: 0}].

Comment: for that I figured that I need on User a reflection of a Questions collection, so I can just increment the option that I need when a User2 is answering that option. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: I need a schema so that every User will have all questions and options for them on it, so I can just increment options when I need. or something else if you have a clue :)

Comment: Can't you keep Questions and User in one collection itself? You can mantain embedded documents.

Comment: So if I add or delete a question from Questions collection will it be reflected on all users from User schema,they will reflect current entries? Can you point me to read about embedded documents? I think I can't keep them in one collection because of an added complexity of managing questions, they should be same for all Users, but if there's a way, please point me in a direction I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to reflect a collection in another document as the way you seem to wish it.

As I understand, the following options are available for you:

- Embed the entire question document inside the User documents in User Collection.
- Just maintain the '_id' of the question document in the User document in User Collection.

Please read on Data Modelling concepts & maintaining relationship between documents from Mongo DB Page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Comment: Thank you, I was looking through this pages today, I will read them thoroughly now :) Can you please point me on a a edatils or example of first option to embed question document.

Comment: Embedding question document inside the user just means that copying the question document inside the user document as shown in your schema. But, no need to copy all the questions, but copy selected questions which the User has answered in under the User document.